# perl split on empty file

Tags: perl

I have basically the following perl I'm working with:

```
open I,$coupon_file or die "Error: File $coupon_file will not Open: $! \n";
while (<I>) {
 $lctr++;
 chomp;
 my @line = split/,/;
 if (!@line) {
     print E "Error: $coupon_file is empty!\n\n";
     $processFile = 0; last;
 }
}
```

I'm having trouble determining what the split/,/ function is returning if an empty file is given to it. The code block if (!@line) is never being executed. If I change that to be

```
if (@line)
```

than the code block is executed. I've read information on the perl split function over at
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html and the discussion [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=41177) about testing for an empty array but not sure what is going on here.

I am new to Perl so am probably missing something straightforward here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are a few tips to make your code more idiomatic:

- The [special variable `$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_LINE_NUMBER) already holds the current line number, so you can likely get rid of `$lctr`.
- Are empty lines really errors, or can you ignore them?
- Pull apart the list returned from `split` and give the pieces names.
- Let Perl do the opening with the ["diamond operator"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators):

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of `sed` and `awk`. Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked, and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to `"-"`, which when opened gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a list of filenames. The loop
>
> ```
> while (<>) {
> ... # code for each line
> }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the following Perl-like pseudo code:
>
> ```
> unshift(@ARGV, '-') unless @ARGV;
> while ($ARGV = shift) {
>   open(ARGV, $ARGV);
>   while (<ARGV>) {
>   ... # code for each line
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> except that it isn't so cumbersome to say, and will actually work.

Say your input is in a file named `input` and contains

```
Campbell's soup,0.50
Mac & Cheese,0.25
```

Then with

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

die "Usage: $0 coupon-file\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

while (<>) {
  chomp;

  my($product,$discount) = split /,/;
  next unless defined $product && defined $discount;

  print "$product => $discount\n";
}
```

that we run as below on Unix:

```
$ ./coupons input
Campbell's soup => 0.50
Mac & Cheese => 0.25
```

Answer (score 5):

1. If the file is empty, the while loop body will not run at all.
2. Evaluating an array in scalar context returns the number of elements in the array.

   `split /,/` always returns a 1+ elements list if `$_` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You might try some debugging:

```
...
chomp;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

print Dumper( { "line is" => $_ } );
my @line = split/,/;
print Dumper( { "split into" => \@line } );

if (!@line) {
...
```

Comment: And of course, always **always** use `use strict; use warnings;` in every single file.

Answer (score 0):

Empty file or empty line?  Regardless, try this test instead of `!@line`.

```
if (scalar(@line) == 0) {
    ...
}
```

The `scalar` method returns the array's length in perl.

Some clarification:

```
if (@line) {
}
```

Is the same as:

```
if (scalar(@line)) {
}
```

In a scalar context, arrays (`@line`) return the length of the array.  So `scalar(@line)` forces `@line` to evaluate in a scalar context and returns the length of the array.

Comment: So using just if (@line) is testing that the array is defined or exists and NOT the size of the array?

Comment: its perl using context's to determine what its going to do.  `if (@line)` is the same as `if (scalar(@line))`, but with the `!@line`, you're not guarantee'ing its being evaluated in a `scalar` context.

Comment: No.  `if (@line)` is the same as `if (scalar(@line))`, which evaluates to true whenever there are elements in the list.

Comment: btw, just tested `!@line` and its the same as `scalar(@line) == 0`, so no real biggie there.  Regardless, eugene has a good point that the `if (!@line)` won't happen at all if the file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you're trying to detect if the line is empty (which your code is trying to) or whether the whole file is empty (which is what the error says).

If the line, please fix your error text and the logic should be like the other posters said (or you can put `if ($line =~ /^\s*$/)` as your if).

If the file, you simply need to test `if (!$lctr) {}` **after** the end of your loop - as noted in another answer, the loop will not be entered if there's no lines in the file.